# Dropdown menu overflow not working when inside a bootstrap nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown menu which works great:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-left">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <i class="icon-map-marker icon-large"></i> Change Site
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    &nbsp;
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="arSiteList">
        <li>
            <a href='#'><b>Select a site</b></a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the list of dropdown items is longer than the screen, scrolling the mouse wheel will scroll down through the list of items. This is perfect.

However, when I moved the dropdown menu into the nav bar, it stopped working:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" >
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="http://portal.parworksapi.com/ar/mars/portal/developer">PAR Works</a>
            <div class="btn-group pull-left">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <i class="icon-map-marker icon-large" ></i> My Sites <span class="caret"></span>
            </a> &nbsp;
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="arSiteList" style="overflow: scroll;">
                <li><a href='#'><b>Select a site</b></a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The dropdown still opens, but when the list of items is too long it's impossible to scroll through them.

How can I make scrolling work inside the nav bar?

Comment: Definitely make a Jsfiddle or something to demonstrate the problem. Don't think this is solvable if we can only see the HTML. Are you using CSS or javascript for the drop down menu?

Answer (score 0):

Check all parent elements of your menu on existing "overflow: hidden;" property in CSS